# Primefaces Data Exporter : Exporting data issue

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I have an List of List. lets say student and address. one to many relationship. In my data table there are 3 columns for the Name, Surname, Age related to the Student and In a single column I need to show address with concatenating the following fields like, address1, address2, city, country.Now I need to export this table by using `<p:dataExporter>`. When I try to export as Excel the corresponding column of Address is exported as Object (org.primefaces.uirepeat. blah blah..)

My code is

```
<p:dataTable value="#{manager.studentList}" var="item" id="studentData">
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.name}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Surname</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.surname}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Age</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.age}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Address</f:facet>
               <ui:repeat value="#{studentBean.addressList}" var="address">
                <h:outputText value="#{address.address1}" /> <br />
               <h:outputText value="#{address.address2}" /> <br />
                <h:outputText value="#{address.city}" /> <br />
               <h:outputText value="#{address.country}" />
               </ui:repeat>
            </p:column> 
        </p:dataTable>

        <h:commandLink>
        <p:graphicImage name="/images/excel.png" />
        <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="studentData" fileName="studentdetails" pageOnly="true"/>
    </h:commandLink>
```

Suggest me some way to export. even I tried with c:forEach and columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p:dataTable value="#{manager.studentList}" rowIndexVar="index" var="item" id="studentData">
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.name}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Surname</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.surname}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Age</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.age}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Address</f:facet>
            <c:forEach var="address" items="#{studentBean.addressList.get(index).address}">
                <h:outputText value="#{address.address1}" />,
                <h:outputText value="#{address.address2}"/>,
                <h:outputText value="#{address.city}" />,
                <h:outputText value="#{address.country}" />
            </c:forEach>
        </p:column> 
    </p:dataTable>

    <h:commandLink>
    <p:graphicImage name="/images/excel.png" />
    <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="studentData" fileName="studentdetails" pageOnly="true"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

i trying with c:forEach is ok